# How to run a python script from a password protected zip

Tags: python, zip, obfuscation, password-protection, pyz

I know python modules/scripts can be run from within a zip archive, as outlined here: 
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0441/
and
https://blogs.gnome.org/jamesh/2012/05/21/python-zip-files/

But my question is:

Is it possible to password protect this archive or .pyz file and run it with another small python script that will send the password and then run the `__main__.py` ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed something like this for myself, so I made it. You need the module found here: https://github.com/Dakkaron/ArchiveImporter

Then you can just use it like this:

```
python ArchiveImporter.py [zipfile] [-p=password] [args...]
```

Works for both Python2 and Python3.

The module can also be used from code:

```
# First import the ArchiveImporter module
import ArchiveImporter
# Then add the password encrypted file you want to import from using addZip(zippath, password)
ArchiveImporter.addZip("test.pyz", "password")
# Now import modules from the archive as usual
import testmod
```

Answer (score 3):

The code that manages the import is inside the `zipimport` module.
Reading the archive is done in the function [`getdata`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1aacc96906ef710139722ebda529ed8500c369de/Modules/zipimport.c#L1062)
It supposes that the file is unencrypted by decompressing it (see [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1aacc96906ef710139722ebda529ed8500c369de/Modules/zipimport.c#L1162)).

So no, unfortunately it does not seem possible to use encrypted file directly from the command line. However you can imagine a wrapper that do this by using [importlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html) (an [example](http://thomassileo.com/blog/2012/12/21/dynamically-load-python-modules-or-classes/)).